# How to nest content in Php?

Tags: php

In JSP you can create tags like this:

```
<myns:mytag>
 <p>Content</p>
</myns:mytag>
```

and process the content in mytag implementation. Is it possible to something like that in php?

Comment: Is this to do with what templating system you use eg Smarty, Twig, etc?

Comment: No just a basic question I was wondering about

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about nesting tags in **output** of PHP, then the answer is yes. PHP doesn't care about the string you output.

Answer (score 0):

Let's play for a while and say this is your XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html xmlns:mn="http://example.com">
    <head>
        <mn:title>Foor</mn:title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>Navigation</div>
        <mn:content>
            Lorem ipsum
        </mn:content>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's stored in `$data` and you will parse it with following class:

```php
class Parser {
    // DOMDocument
    protected $xml;

    // Handles mn:title
    protected function actionTitle( DOMNode $node){
        $title = $this->xml->createElement( 'title', 'My dynamic title');
        $node->parentNode->replaceChild( $title, $node);
    }

    // Handles mn:content
    protected function actionContent( DOMNode $node){
        $content = $this->xml->createElement( 'div', 'Lorem ipsum sit dolor');
        $node->parentNode->replaceChild( $content, $node);
    }

    // Initializes data
    public function __construct( $data){
        $this->xml = new DOMDocument();
        $this->xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $this->xml->loadXML( $data);
        $this->xml->formatOutput = true;
    }

    // Browse all elements
    public function parse() {
        $list = $this->xml->getElementsByTagNameNS( 'http://example.com', '*');
        while( $list->length){
            $node = $list->item(0);
            $tagName = ucfirst( substr( $node->nodeName, strpos( $node->nodeName, ':') + 1));
            echo $tagName . "\n"; // Title, Content
            $funcName = 'action' . $tagName;

            $this->$funcName( $node);

            $list = $this->xml->getElementsByTagNameNS( 'http://example.com', '*');
        }
    }

    // Get
    public function get(){
        return $this->xml->saveXML();
    }
}

// And build some output
$parser = new Parser( $data);
$parser->parse();
echo $parser->get();
```

We are taking advantage of function [`getElementsByTagNameNS()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php), of course this is just heavy example and you'll need to build it more in depth, but at least you'll get idea how does this **may** work :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Comment says basic PHP, no templating system.

You could turn on output buffering at `<myns:mytag>`, turn it off at `</myns:mytag>` then grab the output and process it. That's a bit clunky tho. http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

I would look at a template system (I would advise that in general anyway) and see what they have to offer.